# Immutable.js mapping over keys in Safari

Tags: safari, reactjs, immutable.js

I'm facing this weird issue in Safari where I'm getting this error in the console - 
*Warning: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child.*

On seeing further, I've isolated the issue to mapping over Immutable collection. Here's the code snippet -

```
    var items = Immutable.fromJS([
      {id: 1, val: "foo"},
      {id: 2, val: "bar"},
      {id: 3, val: "moo"},
      {id: 4, val: "baz"}
    ]);

    var tree = items.map(function(item, i) {
      return <p key={i}>{item.get('val')}</p>
    });

    return (
        <div className="tree-view">
            {tree}
        </div>
    )
```

When this is rendered, you can see that somehow those `<span>` elements are being created which are actually properties of the Immutable List object namely - size, capacity, origin, level etc. These span tags are the cause of the error.

[image]

Any idea why this happening? (I've tried replicating this issue in a standalone JSbin but unfortunately I was unable to do so)

Comment: Could it be that `tree` is an Immutable List, you could change `{tree}` to `{tree.toJS()}` on the third last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a cause of this issue, however, I fixed it simply by importing Immutable in my app.js file (even though it didn't require it).

Here's the relevant commit - https://github.com/prakhar1989/react-surveyman/commit/1ed80fb458c005214bc03395cc1e0fd374097dfc

Comment: Prakhar, I am seeing the same problem in Safari in my development environment. These random numbers (size/origin/capacity/level) show up in my HTML. In production these issues go away (after browserify/babelify/uglify). Did you figure out what was going on? Thanks!

Comment: Nope! I was seeing this problem in both dev and prod, so I just added the require statement and that fixed the problem in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue.  When I do not call `toJS()` but do `require('immutable')` then I get the warning about fragments but not the extra spans, and when I call `toJS()` but do not have 'immutable' required, then I get no extra spans and no warnings.

After a little digging in the React issues, I found this one: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4235

Even though it specifically talks about iOS, I have seen the same issue in desktop Safari as well as Mobile Safari.

The solution suggests using a polyfill for Babel, which worked for me.

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

I had to add the polyfill as an entry in my webpack config like this:

```
entry: ['babel/polyfill', './app/client.js']
```

Works for me now on desktop and mobile.